# Use OpenMP on M2 Mac with R and data.table

Tags: r, macos, data.table, openmp, apple-m1

I am struggling to use OpenMP with R and data.table on an M2 Mac Running macOS Ventura 13.3.1. I am following the instructions at https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In summary:

1. OpenMP seems to be correctly installed
2. I have updated `~.R/Makevars` in line with the instructions
3. It doesn't seem that `~.R/Makevars` is loading in R
4. R SessionInfo

#### OpenMP seems to be correctly installed

I believe that I have successfully installed OpenMP in line with the instructions as suggested by the following output:

```r
file.exists(
  "/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib",
  "/usr/local/include/ompt.h",
  "/usr/local/include/omp.h",
  "/usr/local/include/omp-tools.h"
  )
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

When I try to compile the following `openmp_test.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Hello from thread %d\n", thread_id);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with `clang -Xclang -fopenmp -lomp openmp_test.c -o openmp_test`

I can run the program with `./openmp_test` and get the output

```
Hello from thread 2
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 3
Hello from thread 8
Hello from thread 1
Hello from thread 4
Hello from thread 11
Hello from thread 7
Hello from thread 10
Hello from thread 6
Hello from thread 9
Hello from thread 5
```

#### I have updated ~.R/makevars in line with the instructions

```r
readLines("~/.R/Makevars")
# [1] "CPPFLAGS += -Xclang -fopenmp"
# [2] "LDFLAGS += -lomp"            
# [3] "TEST = test1234"
```

#### It doesn't seem that `~.R/Makevars` is loading in R

I'm not sure exactly how `~.R/Makevars` works, but it doesn't seem that these environment variables are loading in R:

```r
Sys.getenv("CPPFLAGS")
# [1] ""
Sys.getenv("LDFLAGS")
# [1] ""
Sys.getenv("TEST")
# [1] ""
```

In shell,

```bash
ls -al ~/.R/Makevars
# -rw-------  1 chandler  62 May 31 07:08 /Users/chandler/.R/Makevars
```

I have also, tried to change the permissions of the file

```bash
chmod 600 ~/.R/Makevars
```

And I've tried to update my `.Renviron` to

```
R_MAKEVARS_USER=~/.R/Makevars
```

Now

```r
Sys.getenv("R_MAKEVARS_USER")
# [1] "~/.R/Makevars"
```

I am not sure of the expected output, but none of these approaches seem to be solving the issue.

#### R SessionInfo

```r
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.3.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/Denver
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices
[4] utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up following the instructions here and was able to get data.table working with OpenMP:

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5419#issuecomment-1465023581

For the `data.table` installation, my `~/.R/Makevars` file looked liked this:

```
LDFLAGS += -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib -lomp
CPPFLAGS += -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -Xclang -fopenmp
```

To get other packages working with OpenMP, I installed the GNU Fortran compiler as suggested here: https://mac.r-project.org/tools/

To install the `fst` package, I first had to uncomment out the `CPPFLAGS` line in `~/.R/Makevars` and add the lines for `fst` [here](https://github.com/fstpackage/fst/issues/263#issuecomment-996324626).

So, my `~/.R/Makevars` looked like this:

```
LDFLAGS += -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib -lomp
## CPPFLAGS += -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -Xclang -fopenmp

CXX1X=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX98=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX11=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX14=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX17=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
```

I then installed the `fst` package by invoking R in the terminal and using `install.packages("fstcore", type="source")` and `install.packages("fst", type="source").

I similarly installed the `fixest` package: `install.packages("fixest", type="source")`

I removed the comment in front `CPPFLAGS`, so my final `~/.R/Makevars` looks like this:

```
LDFLAGS += -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib -lomp
CPPFLAGS += -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -Xclang -fopenmp

CXX1X=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX98=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX11=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX14=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX17=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
```

In the end, everything seems to work:

```r
library(data.table); library(fst); library(fixest);
data.table::getDTthreads()
# [1] 6
fst::threads_fst()
# [1] 12
fixest::getFixest_nthreads()
# [1] 6
```

So, for me, in `~/.R/Makevars`, the line

```
CPPFLAGS += -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -Xclang -fopenmp
```

is necessary to install `data.table` but needs to commented out to install other packages that also rely on OpenMP